# Random forest classification and train/test split

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I'm moving my first steps in machine learning in general and with R in particular. I used python's sklearn before but I'm completely new with R. For a university project I'm trying a random forest on a gene expression dataset for educational purposes. I'm trying to predict mental disorders (bipolar disorder, depression or schizophrenia) using gene expression of various brain cells. My script currently looks like this:

```
library(randomForest)

train_ind <- sample.int(n = nrow(GSMdata),
                         size = floor(0.75*nrow(GSMdata)),
                         replace = F)
RFtrainSet <- data[,train_ind]
RFtestSet <- data[,-train_ind]
RFtrainLabel <- GSMdata$Disease_State[train_ind]
RFtestLabel <- GSMdata$Disease_State[-train_ind]

RFmodel <- randomForest(x = t(RFtrainSet),
                        y = RFtrainLabel,
                        ntree = 100)

table(RFtestLabel, predict(object = RFmodel, 
                           newdata = t(RFtestSet)))
```

Where `data` is a large matrix object and `GSMdata` is a dataframe with the feature of each sample (each column in the matrx represent the gene expression of each sample).
The output of the `table` function looks like this:

```
RFtestLabel                 bipolar disorder control major depressive disorder schizophrenia
  bipolar disorder                         0       7                         6             7
  control                                  0       7                         6             0
  major depressive disorder                0       5                         2             2
  schizophrenia                            0       1                         7             2
```

Frequently when I sample the data a class does not appear in the test dataset as you can see in the sample above. Is this a problem? If yes, is there a function that helps me in having homogeneous test samples?

### Data Example

`data` matrix:

```
          GSM1304852  GSM1304853  GSM1304854 GSM1304855 GSM1304856
1007_s_at  2.3945368  2.27518369  2.16116298  1.9641833  2.1322526
1053_at    0.1051084  0.06160802  0.34217618  0.3593916  0.2235696
117_at    -0.4597124 -0.52310349 -0.44360591 -0.6370277 -0.3511470
121_at     0.9333566  1.13180904  0.99756999  1.0079778  0.9720455
1255_g_at -0.2399138  0.10112324 -0.04087979 -0.2185137 -0.2991786
```

`GSMdata` example:

```
                   title geo_accession Age    Disease_State Gender  pH  PMI Race RIN      tissue
GSM1304852 bipolar_hip_10    GSM1304852  52 bipolar disorder      M 6.7 23.5    W 6.3 hippocampus
GSM1304853 bipolar_hip_11    GSM1304853  50 bipolar disorder      F 6.4 11.7    W 6.8 hippocampus
GSM1304854 bipolar_hip_12    GSM1304854  28 bipolar disorder      F 6.3 22.3    W 7.7 hippocampus
GSM1304855 bipolar_hip_13    GSM1304855  55 bipolar disorder      F 6.4 17.5    W 7.6 hippocampus
GSM1304856 bipolar_hip_14    GSM1304856  58 bipolar disorder      M 6.8 27.7    W 7.0 hippocampus
```

Comment: I would have thought the bigger problem would be where the test set has classes not in the train set. You could try sampling within classes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick dplyr solution to sample within class, no special function needed.  I'm using the iris dataset as an example, but you can quickly adapt it to your data.

```
library(dplyr)
data(iris)
labels <- iris %>% dplyr::select(Species) %>% 
    sample_frac(1) %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    mutate(set = rep(c(rep("train",3),"test"), length.out=n()))

table(labels$Species, labels$set)

             test train
  setosa       12    38
  versicolor   12    38
  virginica    12    38
```

Also, I would recommend the `ranger` random forest package, as it is faster.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is through using `stratified` (from `splitstackshape` package) and using `sqldf` (to make SQL queries) as below:

```
set.seed(1231) 
data(iris)

data <- iris
data$ID <- seq.int(nrow(data)) #Why? remove it and run this again without this bit and you will see the difference.

# making stratified train samples
m_trn <- data.frame((splitstackshape::stratified(data, "Species", 0.5))) #0.5 is percent of training data in each class
m_tst <- (sqldf::sqldf('SELECT * FROM data EXCEPT SELECT * FROM m_trn'))
```